# Unknown column using multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to join two tables twice. One with different rows and another time for different rows but I am getting the below error,

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'p1.ID' in 'on clause'
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT p1.ID, p1.post_title, p1.post_excerpt, p2.meta_value, p1.guid, p4.guid
FROM wp_posts AS p1, wp_postmeta AS p3
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta p2
        ON p1.ID = p2.post_id 
        AND p2.meta_key = '_price'
        AND p1.post_type = 'product'
        AND p1.post_status = 'publish'
    INNER JOIN wp_posts p4
        ON p4.ID = p3.post_id 
        AND p3.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
        AND p4.post_type = 'attachment'
```

Edit: below is the query I have made after the answers but it gives me an empty table.

```
SELECT p1.ID, p1.post_title, p1.post_excerpt, p2.meta_value, p1.guid, p3.guid
FROM wp_posts p1 
     JOIN wp_postmeta p2
     ON p1.ID = p2.post_id AND
        p2.meta_key = '_price' AND
        p1.post_type = 'product' AND
        p1.post_status = 'publish' 
     JOIN wp_posts p3
     ON p3.ID = p2.post_id AND 
        p2.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
     JOIN wp_postmeta p4
     ON p4.post_id = p3.ID AND
        p3.post_type = 'attachment';
```

Comment: Explicit `JOIN` chains are evaluated before comma separated joins. Within an explicit `JOIN` chain, only already specified tables' columns may be referenced.

Answer (score 2):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Your problem is a scoping problem and easily fixed.

When you do so, you'll notice that `p3` seems to be missing a join condition on either `id` or `post_id`.  This is the structure of the query that you want:

```
SELECT p1.ID, p1.post_title, p1.post_excerpt, p2.meta_value, p1.guid, p4.guid
FROM wp_posts p1 JOIN
     wp_postmeta p2
     ON p1.ID = p2.post_id AND
        p2.meta_key = '_price' AND
        p1.post_type = 'product' AND
        p1.post_status = 'publish' JOIN
     wp_posts p3
     ON p3.? = p2.? AND  -- What join condition do you intend here?
        p3.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' JOIN
     wp_postmeta p4
     ON p4.ID = p2.post_id AND
        p4.post_type = 'attachment';
```

Comment: I added your query (also added the missing condition). I am still getting error `#1054 - Unknown column 'p4.guid' in 'field list'`

Comment: @FahadUddin . . . That would suggest that `wp_postmeta` does not have a column called `guid`.  Perhaps you intend `p3`.

Answer (score 0):

> *#1054 - Unknown column 'p1.ID' in 'on clause'*

**As per documentation on [*JOIN Syntax*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)**:

> JOIN has higher precedence than the comma operator (,), so the join
>   expression t1, t2 JOIN t3 is interpreted as (t1, (t2 JOIN t3)), not as
>   ((t1, t2) JOIN t3). This affects statements that use an ON clause
>   because that clause can refer only to columns in the operands of the
>   join, and the precedence affects interpretation of what those operands
>   are.
>
> **Example**:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1, t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
> ```
>
> The JOIN takes precedence over the comma operator, so the operands for
>   the ON clause are t2 and t3. Because t1.i1 is not a column in either
>   of the operands, the result is an Unknown column 't1.i1' in 'on
>   clause' error.

Hence change your join clauses accordingly and frame the sql statement.